# Is there a way to do T test in RUBY?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to do T test in RUBY? For example, what packages might be needed? I have searched some packages related to statistics but none of them is able to do T test or other statistical tests.

Comment: I would think most statistics gems would support t-tests. One to look at is [Statsample](https://github.com/clbustos/statsample/). One of the examples is for t-tests. Also, there are ways to [use R from Ruby](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v29/i04/paper).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [statsample](https://code.google.com/p/ruby-statsample/) seems to provide it.
There is even an example [here](https://github.com/clbustos/statsample/blob/master/examples/t_test.rb).

A one sided test:

```
require 'statsample'

Statsample::Analysis.store(Statsample::Test::T) do
  a=rnorm(10)
  t_1=Statsample::Test.t_one_sample(a,{:u=>50})
  summary t_1
end

Statsample::Analysis.run_batch
```

**output**:

```
Analysis 2014-09-04 12:43:55 +0200
= Statsample::Test::T
  == One Sample T Test
    Sample mean: 0.2265 | Sample sd: 0.9062 | se : 0.2866
    Population mean: 50.0000
    t(9) = -173.6986, p=0.0000 (both tails)
    CI(95%): -50.4217 - -49.1253
```

Comment: I think this is actually a two-sided test (the output says "both tails", and it seems like two-sided t-tests are the default in this gem)